# The same code runs with different results - LWC

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, lightning-progressindicator, lightning-progressstep

This is the result I run in **component-library**

Next and previous steps work fine
[image]

This is the result of my run at **SandBox Org**
[image]
The `currentStep` value was not obtained correctly.

HTML

```
<template>
    <div class="slds-box">
        <lightning-layout vertical-align="center">
            <lightning-layout-item size="1" flexibility="auto">
                <lightning-button-icon icon-name="action:back" onclick={handleBackStep}></lightning-button-icon>
            </lightning-layout-item>
            <lightning-layout-item size="10" flexibility="auto">
                <lightning-progress-indicator current-step={currentStep}>
                    <lightning-progress-step label="1" onclick={handleStepBlur} value="1">
                    </lightning-progress-step>
                    <lightning-progress-step label="2" onclick={handleStepBlur} value="2">
                    </lightning-progress-step>
                    <lightning-progress-step label="3" onclick={handleStepBlur} value="3">
                    </lightning-progress-step>
                    <lightning-progress-step label="4" onclick={handleStepBlur} value="4">
                    </lightning-progress-step>
                </lightning-progress-indicator>
            </lightning-layout-item>
            <lightning-layout-item size="1" flexibility="auto">
                <lightning-button-icon icon-name="utility:forward" onclick={handleNextStep}></lightning-button-icon>
            </lightning-layout-item>
        </lightning-layout>
    </div>
</template>
```

JS

```
import { LightningElement, track, wire } from 'lwc';

export default class convertLead extends LightningElement {

    currentStep = '1';
    //progress onclick
    handleStepBlur(event) {
        this.currentStep = event.target.value;
    }

    //Back Step onclick
    handleBackStep(event) {
        console.log('Back = ' + Number(this.currentStep));
        var step = Number(this.currentStep) - 1;
        if (step === 0) {
            return;
        }
        this.currentStep = toString(step);
    }

    //Next Step onclick
    handleNextStep(event) {
        console.log('Next = ' + Number(this.currentStep));
        var step = Number(this.currentStep) + 1;
        if (step === 5) {
            return;
        }
        this.currentStep = toString(step);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would be keeping this as simple as possible ([KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle#:%7E:text=KISS%2C%20an%20acronym%20for%20keep,unnecessary%20complexity%20should%20be%20avoided.)) and stay away from `Number()` and `toString()`, which is the reason of the NaN result.

```
//Back Step onclick
handleBackStep(event) {
    console.log('Back = ' + this.currentStep);
    if (this.currentStep === 0) {
        return;
    }
    --this.currentStep;
}

//Next Step onclick
handleNextStep(event) {
    console.log('Next = ' + this.currentStep);
    if (this.currentStep === 5) {
        return;
    }
    ++this.currentStep;
}
```

#### Update

To allow the step-blur functionality to continue working as expected, you will need two variables in your JS. The first is to act as a numerical counter, second will the string used in the `lightning-progress-indicator`.

```
currentStepCounter = 1;
currentStep = "1";

//progress onclick
handleStepBlur(event) {
    this.currentStep = event.target.value;
    this.currentStepCounter = Number(this.currentStep);
}

//Back Step onclick
handleBackStep(event) {
    if (this.currentStep === 0) return;
    this.currentStepCounter--;
    this.currentStep = this.currentStepCounter.toString();
}

//Next Step onclick
handleNextStep(event) {
    if (this.currentStep === 5) return;
    this.currentStepCounter++;
    this.currentStep = this.currentStepCounter.toString();
}
```

Comment: Hi  @TSmith  With the code you provided, 'progress 'cannot be assigned correctly

Comment: This means you also need to change the initial declaration of `currentStep` to be `currentStep = 1`.

Comment: @ZhangOu see my update.